Sort files and folders in ascending order of size
How can I use du -h to sort the displayed files and directories in ascending order of size?

If you don't need to recursively list all files in the current working directory, also simply ls -Sr / ls -lSr (with the caveat that all directories would be listed as 4096...)

You can pipe | the output of du's -h, --human-readable to sort's -h, --human-numeric-sort for human format numerical based sorting like:
du -h | sort -h

... and descending by adding sort's -r, --reverse like:
du -h | sort -rh

